# improving processing speed of python code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a Python script that manipulates a dataset of 3 million rows, and the CPU usage is 25% only, so how to improve the processing speed by using multiple cores in CPU or full utilization of CPU to increase the processing speed?

Inputs needed on multiprocessing and process pool.

Comment: Improving formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

```py
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

def some_function_you_want_executed_in_parallel(args):
   pass  # logic goes here

arg_list = []  # put input arguments here

results = pool.map(some_function_you_want_executed_in_parallel, arg_list)
```